Custom build kernel keeps reverting to generic version by itself
I have Ubuntu 22.04.04 LTS with  Kernel Version 5.15.0-112-generic installed. I built a custom version with CMA feature enabled, and it is built as
Linux nai-68int6 5.15.0-117-generic #127+cma SMP Thu Aug 1 11:52:16 EDT 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Installed all the deb files created, and it be booted with CMA enabled.
But for some reason, sometimes, it is booted as
Linux nai-68int6 5.15.0-117-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 5 20:13:28 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

without CMA enabled.
I have removed update-notifier. and It still happens for some unknown reason. And I don't know why it is changed to
#127-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 5 20:13:28 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

How to prevent this from reverting?
Thank you,
David

After built and installed, it is booted as "#127+cma", output by uname -a. Then for some reason, after some time later, it it booted as "#127-Ubuntu". For both cases, the output from uname -r command is: "5.15.0-117-generic".

Please edit your question to add new information or clarifications. Avoid commenting on your own question.

Does the new kernel appear in GRUB?

I was answering your comments, not repeating commenting my own question

when all the newly built deb files, installed for the first time, it creates " 5.15.0-117-generic" grub menu entry. If I reinstall deb files, it keeps the same menu entry. After reinstalling, uname -a command outputs with +cma, and CMA is enabled.

Since it's installed, it's showing in GRUB, and it's bootable (shows up in uname), it seems like you could uninstall the Ubuntu-provided kernel, or you could edit GRUB to prefer your custom kernel.

Not sure how to uninstall the Ubuntu-provided kernel. In the /boot folder, it only has 5.15.0.-117-generic

Do not uninstall the Ubuntu provided kernel (to prevent further issues in future, just let it be as it is), but instead, configure grub to use your kernel by default.

Both kernels with and without +cma are booted from the same image file: initrd.img-5.15.0-117-generic and vmlinuz-5.15.0-117-generic. How to configure grub to use my kernel with +cma ?
